# jquery how to retrieve the number of characters in a p tag?

Tags: jquery, character

my problem is very simple: I want to know how many characters are inside a 'p' tag and if the number is over 100 fire an event on hover.
I tried to retrieve the char number like this:

```
var charLength = $('.myPar').val().length;
<p class="myPar">this is the content of the paragraph</p>
```

it returns always zero as value and it seems to work only for textarea or input tags.
Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Mauro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('.myPar:first').html().length`
or
`$('.myPar:first').text().length`
depending on your use case

Answer (score 0):

replace .val() with .text()

```
var charLength = $('.myPar').text().length;
```